# How to configure istio to use external monitoring system (Prometheus and Grafana)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, istio

I want to configure istio in such a way that it does not uses Prometheus or Grafana which come by default with it. I want to use my existing Prometheus and Grafana which is already deplyoed in cluster. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what cluster environment do You use? How was Your cluster deployed? What is Your kubernetes version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your existing prometheus with a scrape configuration.For prometheus config you can use this [ConfigMap](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/manifests/istio-telemetry/prometheus/templates/configmap.yaml). For grafana you need to configure your prometheus as datasource and you can use this [configMap](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/manifests/istio-telemetry/grafana/templates/configmap.yaml) for that. You can generate the ConfigMaps using helm template and use.

Check this [guide](https://istiobyexample.dev/prometheus/)